# SQL Server 2000 from ASP.net

Tags: sql-server

I want detailed step by step for connecting to SQL Server 2000 from ASP.net.....

I am trying but getting Connection Open Error..

Answer (score 0):

this video will explain it for you

http://www.asp.net/learn/sql-videos/video-110.aspx

and this link will give you more videos about how you handle your database

http://www.asp.net/learn/sql-videos/